# Search results when closing as duplicate have duplicates, not sorted well

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, search, duplicate-questions

When I want to close something as a duplicate, I almost always try to use the search in the "close" dialog box, but end up getting frustrated and resort to using site search in a new tab.

Here is a concrete example.  On Webmasters we have a policy that we don't accept questions asking for content management system recommendations.  We mark them all duplicate of this question: [Which Content Management System (CMS)/Wiki should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-wiki-should-i-use)

When I use site search for "CMS" I get directed to the [CMS tag page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cms) which has that question right at the top.   When I search when closing as a duplicate the search results are much worse:

[image]

Even if I make my search much more explicit (pretty much the entire title of the question) I can't get the correct question to come up:

[image]

There seem to be several things that could be improved here:

- When searching for something that matches a tag, showing the tag page results would be better
- Questions closed as duplicate should be omitted from these search results (I don't want to mark the question as a duplicate of a duplicate)
- It would be nice to be able to sort by votes the same way that you can with site search
- The relevance algorithm seem broken.  In my second example, why doesn't a question that has all the words in the title come up before the results that have the words in the body?  It is significantly worse than site search [which does not have this problem](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=which+content+management+systems+cms+wiki+should+I+use).